# Select a piece on ChartPlotter

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

Please tell me how to select a piece on ChartPlotter I can not understand..

[like this](http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130516/m6RJ9744.jpg)

Comment: Please, try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/about. Namely do not ask about: **Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)**

Answer (score 1):

Try CTRL+Mouse. Use RightClick for get a help